# Как параллельно итерироваться по нескольким последовательностям?

Tags: c#

```
foreach (string command in commands)
    {
        foreach (string name in namescommands)
        {
            Console.writeline(command + name);
            break;
        }
    }
```

В данном коде выходит такой результат:

```
command name
command name2
command name3
```

А мне необходимо, что бы было вот так.

```
command name
command2 name2
command3 name3
```

Уже не приложу голову как это реализовать...

Comment: Зачем вы удаляли перед этим этот вопрос? Или опять откуда-то одинаковые вопросы с курсов каких-то идут? )

Comment: Нет, просто я думал что нашёл ответ на тот вопрос. Я сейчас ни на каком курсе, а пишу один плагин к игре. Вроде сначала показалось что сделал, а вот теперь задал ещё один)

Comment: Если у вас две разные коллекции, но с одинаковым числом элементов, то зачем вам `foreach`? Используйте `for` и по индексу выводите то, что хотите, либо объединяйте их. А вообще, вы сейчас страдаете из-за просчета в вашей архитектуре, ибо мало кто содержит два несвязанных друг с другом списка. Сделайте словарь, например и ключом пусть будет имя, а команда значением этого имени. Если команд много, то `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`, где вы уже под каждое имя сможете задать несколько значений.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
int countNameCommands = 3;    
for (int i = 0; i < countNameCommands; i++)
{
    string name = namescommands[i];
    string command = commands[i];
    Console.WriteLine(name + command);
}
```

Вывод:

```
name command
name1 command1
name2 command2
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно параллельно итерироваться по двум последовательностям, в `Python` это довольно стандартная вещь, а в `C#` не все знают, что там есть [Enumerable.Zip](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=netframework-4.7)

Что-то типа такого у вас будет:

```
foreach (var (command,name) in commands.Zip(namescommands, (command, name) => (command, name)))
{
    Console.writeline(command + name);
}
```

Но точно за синтаксис не поручусь, надо уточнять.

Comment: если быть точнее, то `commands.Zip(namescommands, (command, name) => (command, name))`

Comment: @timur А точно функция нужна, по дефолту Zip сам ValueTuple не сделает?

Comment: нет, функцию передавать обязательно

Comment: спасибо, исправлю тогда. эх, то ли дело питон...

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Но у меня с ним появлялись ошибка, насчёт версии C#. Так их и не решил. Ответ оставил ниже, может кому понадобится.